# How to Use who/w with Non-Interactive SSH logins

Tags: ssh, users, sshd, putty, who

I'd like to perform selective shutdown of a server in my house after backing-up over SSH. My post-backup script waits for five minutes and then runs a very short 'safe shutdown' script located on the server. This script was using `who -q` to get the number of users logged on, however as I started executing this script non-interactively, i.e. using `ssh user@server /home/common/bin/SafeShutdown.sh` (well actually using PuTTY's plink right now but should make no difference), the user count being found was 0 if no interactive users were present. How can I either get who/w to work with non-interactive logins, or else use another method as an **unpriveliged** user to count how many people are logged on in any way, shape or form?

Thanks

Comment: an easy thing to do is make your non-interactive ssh's use a pseudo-tty, then they will be counted. `ssh -t`.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me, the switch is the same for putty (although a little annoying as normally putty seems to use lower-case switches for disabling and upper-case for enabling capabilities!) It's a good, simple workaround but I don't feel it really answers the question so I'll wait a bit and if no-one else has anything to add I'll put it as an answer and mark it as solved. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As meuh says, the use of a pseudo-terminal may be forced with the -t option, and then the login will show-up with who. However whilst this a home system, if it weren't it still would concern me a little that if someone logged in without using that switch I might be unaware of his presence on my system without looking further into sshd's reporting options!